# CodeIgniter - methodology for writing CMS?

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system

I am building a CMS based on CodeIgniter and Wiredesigz HMVC plugin in order to expand my PHP and in particular OOP knowledge further. So, I have started, and am already stuck with two best practices issues that I hope someone can help with.

1. Should the core of my CMS, which will contain all globally used functions such as logging system events, load scripts and CSS for different modules, etc., reside in a library (that make calls to the Core module model) or in the Core module itself?
2. If I put the core functionality in a module, should my other modules extend the Core (class User extends Core) or should they be stand-alone (User constructor loads Core module)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done more reading on this, but found no real concensus. Some comments said that it depends on what your end objective is. Since there are no other suggestions or answers here, I will consider it a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

you may reference the CMS project `pyrocms` based on codeigniter framework

Comment: Thanks, Fu Xu, I agree that looking at an existing good quality CMS is a good way to go if you want to create a new one for public consumption. Also, if you want to learn, and mess around and improve skills, dissecting a full CMS is also very good - to figure out how things are done across the board, but if you just to get two best practice answers this approach would be rather counterproductive. What are your personal views on the questions I asked above? Thanks in advance :-)